# Data in pickle format not loading into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I got this code that has data stored in pickle format, I am trying to unpickle it. After it successfully ran, it was returning this output: `<__main__.Container at 0x232ac6bde80>`, but I want the data loaded into the DataFrame for further manipulations. I have searched *StackOverflow* for possible solutions to no avail. Kindly help. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
impor numpy as np
import tpickle
import skill_metrics as sm
from sys import version_info

def load_obj(name):
    # Load object from file in pickle format
    if version_info[0] == 2:
        suffix = 'pkl'
    else:
        suffix = 'pkl3'

    with open(name + '.' + suffix, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f) # Python2 succeeds

class Container(object): 
    
    def __init__(self, pred1, pred2, pred3, ref):
        self.pred1 = pred1
        self.pred2 = pred2
        self.pred3 = pred3
        self.ref = ref
        
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Set the figure properties (optional)
    rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8.0, 6.4] #works
#     rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2 # line width for plots
    rcParams.update({'font.size': 12}) # font size of axes text

    # Close any previously open graphics windows
    plt.close("all")
        
    # Read data from pickle file
    load_obj('target_data')
    
df = pd.read_pickle('target_data.pkl')
df
```

Thanks.

Comment: How was the data saved into the pickle file?

Comment: @Nick please forgive me, I absolutely have no idea. I am new to pickle.

Comment: your load_obj function returns an object of the Container class - so it seems to be working. Just try `abc = load_obj('target_data')`, and your value should be in `abc`

Comment: This is what I got after running *abc*:    `<__main__.Container object at 0x00000232A93B2790>`